# PTIJ Where is there a chiyuv kavod?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

With no due respect I humbly  present the forum with this question:

The gemara in brachos says אין מכבדים בגשרים my question is if then where is there a chiyuv of kavod, dont we all know כל העולם כולו גשר צר מאוד?

--confused

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly right! We *aren't* mechabed anyone who is one the gesher - stuck in this world, rather we are mechabed those whose value is in shamayim.

Answer (score 2):

You've incorrectly translated מכבדים . It means "to make heavy". In other words, the expression means that we don't make our lives "heavier" by bridges.

Of course we don't. We have so many difficulties in our lives already. The expression is another way of saying, "Cross the bridge when you get there." I.e., don't add imaginary heavy bridges that aren't necessary, now. Deal with the heavy bridges only once you need to.